# Filter rules as a variables

Tags: richtext, variable, replace

I want to strip every headline tag from all Rich Text fields site-wide.

So I thought about adding a replace filter.

But since this will be site wide I wanted to write the replace rules in a variable:

```
{% set replaceHeadline = '"<h1>" : "<p>", "</h1>" : "</p>"' %}
{{ entry.richText | replace({replaceHeadline}) | raw }}
```

This produces the error:

> A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token
>   "punctuation" of value "}" ("punctuation" expected with value ":").

Is this not possible? Is concatenation with `~` somehow the way to go?

Is there a more sane approach to stripping all headline tags from Rich Text fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to store the complete array into the variable

```
{% set replaceHeadline = {'<h1>': '<p>', '</h1>': '</p>'} %}
{{ entry.richText|replace(replaceHeadline)|raw }}
```

But instead of storing that variable I'd probably just create a macro for that snippet.

_includes/macros.html

```
{% macro formatRichText(string) %}
    {{- string|replace({
        '<h1>': '<p>',
        '</h1>': '</p>'
    })|raw }}
{% endmacro %}
```

_layout.html

```
{% import '_includes/macros' as macros %}
```

You can now use that helper macro everywhere in your templates

```
{{ macros.formatRichText(entry.richText) }}
```

Another recommendation, have a look at the [RetconHTML](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Change) plugin, a nice little plugin to manipulate HTML with Twig.

```
{{ string|retconChange('h1', 'p') }}
```